# cartographer + move_base

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Cartographer and move_base can not run at the same time, move_base subscribes to the /map topic published by cartographer for navigation, without passing through map_server.
I tried to do this, but the time interval between the two frames of the /cmd_val topic published by move_base reached more than 20 seconds.

```
[ INFO] [1563279138.784172362]: Resizing costmap to 650 X 680 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1563279138.795393838]: Resizing static layer to 650 X 680 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ WARN] [1563279156.227073295]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 10.0000Hz... the loop actually took18.7780 seconds
[ WARN] [1563279156.227821820]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 1.0000Hz... the loop actually took 25.4829 seconds.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328872/cartographer-+-move_base/) by [Tansor](https://answers.ros.org/users/39183/tansor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2019-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You do not need map server when you're running SLAM. Map server is just to expose the /map topic of a previous mapping session stored as an image file.

If you have another source of /map, that is unnecessary.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tansor](https://answers.ros.org/users/39183/tansor/) on 2019-07-18**:
Thanks for your answer！I still have a question, why does the Control loop take so much time?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-07-18**:
You should ask in another question to not mix things. If I answered your question mark as correct so it's off the unanswered questions queue.